# Best way to build denormilazed dataframe with pandas from spotify API

Tags: python, json, pandas

I just downloaded some json from spotify and took a look into the pd.normalize_json().

But if I normalise the data i still have dictionaries within my dataframe. Also setting the level doesnt help.

DATA I want to have in my dataframe:

```
{
  "collaborative": false,
  "description": "",
  "external_urls": {
    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5"
  },
  "followers": {
    "href": null,
    "total": 0
  },
  "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/5?additional_types=track",
  "id": "5",
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 640,
      "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/a",
      "width": 640
    }
  ],
  "name": "Another",
  "owner": {
    "display_name": "user",
    "external_urls": {
      "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/user/user"
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/user",
    "id": "user",
    "type": "user",
    "uri": "spotify:user:user"
  },
  "primary_color": null,
  "public": true,
  "snapshot_id": "M2QxNTcyYTkMDc2",
  "tracks": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/100&additional_types=track",
    "items": [
      {
        "added_at": "2020-12-13T18:34:09Z",
        "added_by": {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/user/user"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/user",
          "id": "user",
          "type": "user",
          "uri": "spotify:user:user"
        },
        "is_local": false,
        "primary_color": null,
        "track": {
          "album": {
            "album_type": "album",
            "artists": [
              {
                "external_urls": {
                  "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1dfeR4Had"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1dfDbWqFHLkxsg1d",
                "id": "1dfeR4HaWDbWqFHLkxsg1d",
                "name": "Q",
                "type": "artist",
                "uri": "spotify:artist:1dfeRqFHLkxsg1d"
              }
            ],
            "available_markets": [
              "CA",
              "US"
            ],
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/6wPXmlLzZ5cCa"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6wPXUJ9LzZ5cCa",
            "id": "6wPXUmYJ9zZ5cCa",
            "images": [
              {
                "height": 640,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab676620a47",
                "width": 640
              },
              {
                "height": 300,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0620a47",
                "width": 300
              },
              {
                "height": 64,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab603e6620a47",
                "width": 64
              }
            ],
            "name": "The (Deluxe ",
            "release_date": "1920-07-17",
            "release_date_precision": "day",
            "total_tracks": 15,
            "type": "album",
            "uri": "spotify:album:6m5cCa"
          },
          "artists": [
            {
              "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1dg1d"
              },
              "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1dsg1d",
              "id": "1dfeR4HaWDbWqFHLkxsg1d",
              "name": "Q",
              "type": "artist",
              "uri": "spotify:artist:1dxsg1d"
            }
          ],
          "available_markets": [
            "CA",
            "US"
          ],
          "disc_number": 1,
          "duration_ms": 21453,
          "episode": false,
          "explicit": false,
          "external_ids": {
            "isrc": "GBU6015"
          },
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5716J"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5716J",
          "id": "5716J",
          "is_local": false,
          "name": "Another",
          "popularity": 73,
          "preview_url": null,
          "track": true,
          "track_number": 3,
          "type": "track",
          "uri": "spotify:track:516J"
        },
        "video_thumbnail": {
          "url": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "limit": 100,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total": 1
  },
  "type": "playlist",
  "uri": "spotify:playlist:fek"
}
```

So what are best practices to read nested data like this into one dataframe in pandas?

I'm glad for any advice.

EDIT:

so basically I want all keys as columns in my dataframe. But with normalise it stops at "tracks.items" and if I normalise this again i have the recursive problem again.

Comment: that would be quite a long dataframe, what data do you actually need?

Comment: kindly post ur expected output. let's have a visual of what u r after

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the information you are looking for. Take a look at pandas.read_json() to see if that can work. Also you can select data as such

```
json_output = {"collaborative": 'false',"description": "",  "external_urls": {"spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5"}}
df['collaborative'] = json_output['collaborative'] #set value of your df to value of returned json values
```

Comment: I want to have every key as column, but not flattened.

Comment: df.columns = list(data.keys()) may be a start

Comment: that's not the solution Im looking for. There must be some handy ways to do this, instead of selecting any single data column I want to have.